# Invalid left-hand side in assignment for no apparent reason

Tags: javascript

I'm receiving  that kind of error, I can't copy the whole code (quite big), but I can find a reason why that happens.

In this portion of code

```
 '...      })})(jQInteractives);</script></textarea>')   

     } else if (ide == "feverchart") {

        $("#codeArea").append('<textarea>'+
          '<style>.stretch:after {content:     ....
```

I'm using ... just to indicate the code follows there, but it's not a problem of what's around it, even if I move it, the problem always appears to be in the line

```
 $("#codeArea").append('<textarea>'+
```

It has nothing to do with the '+ because I've tried without it and just continuing the line.

I'm using the exact same line in other parts of the complete code without problems, and I don't see the problem here either. 
Any clues?

Per comment, I moved it to a different place, to avoid problems with not properly closing smoething. I have the same problem when I move it here:

```
 if (ide == "blanktemp") {

 } else if (ide == "feverchart") {

        $("#codeArea").append('<textarea>'+
          '<style>.stretch:after {content: ".";display: [... code continues ...]
```

It's always the same line, no matter where I put it.

Comment: The problem lies elsewhere. Perhaps *after* the closing `)` of the `append()` function, but we can't see that. Please post sample code that actually shows the error. We can't diagnose what we can't see.

Comment: Try running your code in a different environment as different JS engines sometimes produce different errors. I've seen a few very cryptic errors by Chrome which FF managed to translate to something understandable.

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks, but it sveeral hundred of lines, so that's why I'm not uploading it all.. I've moved the else if {} around to see where's the problem, but no matter where I put it, it always the same line. So it's not about something not properly closed.

Comment: @ChiquiEsteban Please try to extract that else if so that we can run it ourselves.

Comment: Thanks Nikola, but I get the same error in Firefox... exactly the same language.

Comment: @idmean I moved it to the top, so it's:   if (ide == "blanktemp") {
       
        } else if (ide == "feverchart") {

            $("#codeArea").append('<textarea>'+
              '<style>.stretch:after {content: ".";display: [...]   Going to put in a new comment

Comment: @ChiquiEsteban if all of your assumptions about where the problem is (or isn't) were correct, your code would work. So at least consider the possibility that you're mistaken about what needs to be shown. You've left out the code that's causing the problem. My guess is just a guess, since I have *nothing* to work with. Nothing in the code you've shown  would cause that error.

Comment: Notice that `</script>` you have in your string? Replace that with `<\/script>` and see if that works.

Comment: Copy the code into a pastebin and link it in the comments

Comment: Ok, solved, it was an unexpected string in the textarea I was building. I thought that if there was a problem like that it will be showing in the console as a problem in the line where it was happening, not as a left-hand side in assignment error... Thanks for your help!